# A ply parser should partly treat comments

Tags: python, comments, yacc, ply

I'm trying to produce a ply parser that does not entirely suppress comments.

The typical

`def t_comment(self, t):
        r'(/\*(.|\n)*?\*/)|(//.*)'
        t.lineno += t.value.count('\n')`

only counts lines and suppresses the comments. For most of the cases, this is just fine. But at one specific instance I need the comment. Is there a way to parse only this comment at the special place without having to specify all the other places where a comment can occur?

Comment: Well *what is specific about that instance?*

Comment: please format code in your question accordingly (use the code tags)

Comment: The file I want to parse is some kind of source code with references to other files. Something like an  `external char xxxx; // important comment`. And this comment behind the external references is important. All other comments may be skipped. Is there a way to capture only these and keep it simple for any other occurrences?